# An error occurred when editing a tag excerpt

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I just wanted to edit [a tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/invantive-sql/info) on Stack Overflow. When clicking *Save Edits* it gives me *An error occurred when submitting your post*.

I tried to remove some text from the edit to check if it was related to the text, but it didn't work, even with just the original text.

What went wrong?

Comment: Oh, now [it seems to come through](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40015001/revisions). Still curious what went wrong and how to diagnose it.

Comment: I experienced this in other situations, for example, when I up/downvoted a post or upvoted a comment. In a few seconds later, I was able to vote. I am also curious to know what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Overflow Documentation introduced a "Friendly Name" field, which was not correctly stored in revisions. This made quick edits go bonkers. After the quick edit window ended, normal edits would work.

I've corrected the storing of initial revisions so this should not happen anymore.

This will be deployed in `rev 5145` (`rev 4128` on Stack Overflow)